# Error al proyectar el modelo Lee Carter Obtenido

Tags: r

Inicialmente para ejecutar el modelo Lee Carter con la función: lca del paquete demography, tuve inconvenientes debido a que mis datos poseen la variable edad agrupada por grandes grupos (0-4, 5-14, 15-24, 25-44, 45-64, 65-74 , 75 a +)
me generaba error bajo esta estructura ya que no lograba identificar la edad maxima en mis datos. reemplace los grupos de edad por el valor medio de cada grupo etario (2,10,20,35,55,70,88) y la función la aceptó. pero al aplicar la función forecast sobre el modelo lc obtenido me genera el siguiente error:

forecast.lc.gral <- forecast(lc.gral, h=5)
Error in lt(x, startage, agegroup, sex) : agegroup must be either 1 or 5

creo que este error surge por la estructura de la variable edad, ya que al proyectar con esta función estima la esperanza de vida.

Alguien conocerá una alternativa para proyectar el modelo obtenido?
El otro problema es que mi base de datos registra grupos de edades por lo que me es imposible desagregarlo.

Gracias de antemano.

también opte por enumerar los grupos etarios según 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 y la proyección con forecast corrió sin embargo el resultado no es confiable.